# why js dom api 'querySelector' select itself

Tags: javascript, selectors-api, queryselector

I'm confused why `$1` is `firstBB`, The `querySelector('.aa .bb')` call should execute under `#root` element.

```js
const $1 = document.querySelector('#root').querySelector('.aa .bb');
const $2 = document.querySelector('#root').querySelector('.aa').querySelector('.bb');

document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = `$1 is ${$1.id}; $2 is ${$2.id}`
```

```html
<div class="aa" id="root">
  <div class="bb" id="firstBB">xxx</div>
  <div class="aa">
    <div class="bb" id="secondBB">xxx</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>Result: <span id="result"></span></div>
```

Chrome version: 116.0.5845.188

Is this the correct behavior of `querySelector`?

Comment: Probably due to CSS specificity. Since `#root` has a class called `aa`, I assume selection begins relative to itself.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector#the_entire_hierarchy_counts

Comment: *selectors is first applied to the whole document, not the baseElement, to generate an initial list of potential elements. The resulting elements are then examined to see if they are descendants of baseElement*

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is no bug. It is the specified behaviour.

[Element: querySelector() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector#return_value)

> Return value
>
> The first descendant element of baseElement which matches the specified group of selectors. The entire hierarchy of elements is considered when matching, including those outside the set of elements including baseElement and its descendants; in other words, **selectors is first applied to the whole document, not the baseElement, to generate an initial list of potential elements. The resulting elements are then examined to see if they are descendants of baseElement**. The first match of those remaining elements is returned by the querySelector() method.

(*tbh, i also was under the impression that it would select the second, before reading the documentation right now*)

Comment: Why does it work in such an unintuitive, inefficient manner?

Comment: @Konrad I don't remember enough jQuery to be sure, but shot in the dark: because that's how jQuery did it?

Comment: Ask the people who wrote the specifications....

Comment: @JaredSmith that is not how jquery did it, and that would also not be a good reason for this.

Comment: A request from implementers that was honored? For integration with/due to existing performance optimizations?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I never said it was a *good* reason lol. Thank you for the correction

Comment: @JaredSmith :D yeah, i just meant that i do not think that this would be a part of their reasoning.

Comment: Still confused, what is "descendants"? Why baseElement is the descendant of itself

Comment: @WhiteWang the way `querySelector` works is it will first find all `.aa .bb` elements in the document, so both `#firstBB` and `#secondBB` will be found, and then it will filter those elements for these that are descendants of `#root`. Again both elements are descendants of `root`. And since `querySelector` returns only one element, it will return the first of those, so the `#firstBB`